Cómo hago para que el cronometro que me muestra esta vista no se reinicie a 00:00 cada 5 segundos?
Básicamente estoy intentando crear una vista donde muestre el tiempo de descanso que lleva un empleado con su ficha correspondiente, pero el problema es que el cronómetro va bien hasta que llega al quinto segundo y en lugar de contarlo, se lo saltea, mostrando 00:00 y luego continua normalmente, se reinicia de nuevo en 00:00 y así sucesivamente. Intenté eliminar intervalos pero eso solo deja el cronómetro sin funcionar. Lo que quiero lograr es que el cronómetro no se saltee ningún segundo. Esto se maneja desde un panel de control, el cual funciona bien, cuando se carga una ficha al descanso, aparece en esta vista que funciona mas como un control que lleva uno mismo para saber cuanto tiempo está descansando.
const cronometroIntervals = {};

function actualizarFichas(data) {
    const fichasContenedor = document.getElementById('fichas-descanso');
    const idsAsesoresActivos = new Set(data.map(asesor => asesor.id)); // IDs de asesores que siguen en descanso

function gestionarCronometros(data) {
    data.forEach(asesor => {
        if (!cronometroIntervals[asesor.id]) {
            console.log(`Iniciando cronómetro para el asesor con ID: ${asesor.id}`);
            iniciarCronometro(asesor.id);
        } else {
            console.log(`El cronómetro para el asesor con ID: ${asesor.id} ya está corriendo.`);
        }
    });
}

function cargarFichasEnDescanso() {
    fetch('../php/asesores_en_descanso.php')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log('Datos recibidos del servidor:', data);

            // Actualizar las fichas visibles
            actualizarFichas(data);

            // Asegurarse de que los cronómetros sigan funcionando
            gestionarCronometros(data);
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error al cargar fichas:', error));
}

// Llamar la función para cargar fichas
setInterval(cargarFichasEnDescanso, 5000); // Actualizar fichas cada 7 segundos
cargarFichasEnDescanso(); // Cargar fichas al cargar la página

function iniciarCronometro(asesorId) {
    // Si el cronómetro ya está corriendo, no iniciar otro
    if (cronometroIntervals[asesorId]) {
        console.log(`El cronómetro para el asesor con ID: ${asesorId} ya está corriendo.`);
        return;
    }

    console.log(`Iniciando cronómetro para el asesor con ID: ${asesorId}`);

    // Recuperar el tiempo almacenado del cronómetro o inicializar a 0
    const cronometroData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cronometros') || '{}');
    let tiempoEnSegundos = cronometroData[asesorId] || 0;


    const cronometroElement = document.getElementById(`cronometro-${asesorId}`);
    const tiempoElement = document.getElementById(`tiempo-${asesorId}`);

    if (!cronometroElement || !tiempoElement) {
        console.error('Elementos del cronómetro no encontrados.');
        return;
    }

    // Inicializar cronómetro desde el tiempo almacenado
    cronometroIntervals[asesorId] = setInterval(function() {
        tiempoEnSegundos++;
        actualizarCronometro();
    }, 1000);

    let segundosDesdeUltimoGuardado = 0;

function actualizarCronometro() {
    const minutos = Math.floor(tiempoEnSegundos / 60);
    const segundos = tiempoEnSegundos % 60;
    const tiempoFormateado = `${String(minutos).padStart(2, '0')}:${String(segundos).padStart(2, '0')}`;

    tiempoElement.textContent = tiempoFormateado;

    // Incrementar el contador de segundos desde el último guardado
    segundosDesdeUltimoGuardado++;

    // Guardar el tiempo actualizado en localStorage cada 5 segundos
    if (segundosDesdeUltimoGuardado >= 5) {
        cronometroData[asesorId] = tiempoEnSegundos;
        localStorage.setItem('cronometros', JSON.stringify(cronometroData));
        segundosDesdeUltimoGuardado = 0;  // Reiniciar el contador
    }

    // Cambiar color si ha pasado más de 15 minutos
    if (tiempoEnSegundos >= 15 * 60) {
        cronometroElement.classList.add('rojo');
    } else {
        cronometroElement.classList.remove('rojo');
    }
}
}


function detenerCronometro(asesorId) {
    if (cronometroIntervals[asesorId]) {
        clearInterval(cronometroIntervals[asesorId]);
        delete cronometroIntervals[asesorId];
        console.log(`Cronómetro del asesor con ID: ${asesorId} detenido.`);
    }


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! hay una funcion que se ejecuta exactamente cada 5 segundos.. no entiendo que es lo que no queres que pase...

El código que debes agregar en tu pregunta es el de un [MVCE], es decir un código que reproduzca claramente lo que describes en palabras. En cambio, el código que has puesto es en extremo enredado y depende de elementos del servidor que es solo ruido para la pregunta
